# Rename multiple file with counting in the front in python

Tags: python, naming

I want to add a serial of number in the front of my file name and start with 001, 002, 003,....999

With the code

```
count = 1
for i in list:
    os.rename(i, str(count)+'_'+i[0:-4]+'.jpg')
    count += 1
```

I can get the name start with 1, 2, 3, 4,....999

How to make it start with 001, 002, 003,...to 999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zfill()` and combine it with `enumerate()`:

```
for count, i in enumerate(list):
    os.rename(i, str(count+1).zfill(3)+'_'+i[0:-4]+'.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem

```
print([f"{i:03}" for i in range(999)])
```